# jar files conflict on namespaces

Tags: java, jar, namespaces, conflict

I have two jar file in my project dependencies (gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar and commons-codec-1.5.jar) while both has class with this namespace "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64" so when importing this package I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception because wrong select jar for import. any idea to solve this? remember that both jar file is needed on my project.

Comment: I don't think you have too many options. Either fix the order of jars in classpath or fix the jar that contains unintended version of the class `Base64`.

Comment: we have no unintended version. both classes are using by some other class and also reorder the classpath not worked. more options please

Answer (score 0):

No response! great. too bad that importing package dose not consider jar filename but I figure it out my problem by adding the source code of right package in my project.

Comment: JAR files are only containers - besides containing the types, they have otherwise nothing to do with situation, excepting the ordering in which types are searched/resolved.

Comment: In the up comment I explain that ordering jar libs not work in netBeans.